# UWP/WPF Outsourcing navigation to separate class

Tags: wpf, uwp, navigation

I've tried to outsource my navigation to another class so that I just have one place to look when Navigation is wrong and also when I want to make it independet from my plattform.

**But it seems not to work!**

So my method is like this:

```
private Type _Type { get; set; }

public void Navigate(Navigation target, Navigation from = Navigation.Ignore, object navArgs = null)
{
    _Type = null;
    if (CurrentFrame == null)
        CurrentFrame = (Window.Current.Content as Frame);
    if (from == Navigation.Ignore && target == Navigation.Previous)
    {
        CurrentFrame.GoBack();
        return;
    }
    else if (target == Navigation.UseCase)
    {
        CurrentModul = Modul.Overall;
        _Type = typeof(UseCasePage);
    }
    else if (target == Navigation.Main)
    {
        CurrentModul = Modul.Overall;
        _Type = typeof(MainPage);
    }
    CurrentFrame.Navigate(typeof(_Type), navArgs);
}
```

But it does not work and I can't see what the problem is.

The Navigation element is an enum.

Comment: Where did the `Navigation` class come from? I don't know any such class or enum in uwp

Comment: It's an selfmade enum which I provide instead of the type the page has. And the enum gets validated to navigate to the right typeof(Class)

Comment: Okay I solved my problem since my navigation was way more complex than the snippet I had a return at the main part of the application which got triggered before the navigation got executed.. Thank you a lot for your helped. And sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was simply because of the complexity I lost trace while writing and had a return statement in the method which was executed before navigation could be triggered.

Since I found no sample of how to outsource navigation to a different class o.e. I provide my sample project which I set up to solve my problem.

[SampleProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3f5ztqz384sjsza/SampleNavigationProject.zip?dl=0)